# PHP/MySQL - PDO Library Get Total Number of Rows

Tags: php, pdo

How would I go about getting the total number of rows in a table using the PDO library?

Below is how I execute my queries.

```
$query = " 

"; 

try 
{ 

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 

    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
}
```

**EDIT**

I should have made it more clear, I'm sorry, but I was looking for the PDO way of getting number of rows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [rowcount](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.rowcount.php) in PDO.

1) Useful for delete, update or insert queries

2) See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148555/php-mysql-pdo-library-get-total-number-of-rows/14148730#14148730) of kokx for select queries

Comment: Awesome, I wanted to stick with PDO functions. Thanks =]

Answer (score 2):

A database does not have rows. A table, however, does. What I think that you are looking for, is a SQL query that will count the rows in a table. Which you can do like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM table
```

If you execute that query, the count field in the result will contain the number of rows in the table.